# Kendo UI Tooltip remove/destroy?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-tooltip

How do I remove/destroy an existing tooltip created like:

```
$(td[role=gridcell]").kendoTooltip({ ... });
```

For example, to destroy a grid you do the following:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").destroy();
```

How do I check whether the tooltip exists and/or has been destroyed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While the documentation doesn't list a `destroy` method for kendoToolTip, it does exist.

I would suggest creating your Tooltip like this instead:

```
$("#grid").kendoTooltip({
    filter: "td[role=gridcell]",
    content: "My Other ToolTip"
});
```

Then you can destroy the Tooltip with

```
$("#grid").data("kendoTooltip").destroy();
```

If you create it like this:

```
$("td[role=gridcell]").kendoTooltip({ ... });
```

it will create a widget for each cell (because your jQuery selector selects all cells!), so when you try do this:

```
var myTooltip = $("td[role=gridcell]").data("kendoTooltip");
myTooltip.destroy();
```

it will only return and destroy the widget for the first of the matched elements.

Comment: at the risk of going off-topic, are you aware of the show method has access to any information about the target?

Comment: @jtromans You should probably create another question for this where you show what you're trying to do - I'm not sure what you mean with "any information" and where you're trying to access it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119044/kendo-ui-tooltip-on-show-access-target Done, please let me know what you think.